# How to get all records of all parent records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, associations

I'm needing to create a select box for a form where I list all child records of all parents. How do I do this in my controller? I'm thinking the answer below, but its returning "undefined method nil:NilClass"

```
before_action :get_children

def get_children
  @parents = current_user.parents.all
  @children = @parents.children.all
end
```

Comment: `@parents` is an array so the children of that array would be nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@parents` is an array so the children of that array would be nil.
So you would have to use some type of loop like:

```
def get_children
  children = []
  @parents = current.user.parents.all
  @parents.each do |child|
    children << child
  end
  return children
end
```

Something like this oughta work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array:

```
@children = @parents.map(&:children).flatten.uniq
```

If you want an ActiveRecord::Relation (assuming your model is called Thing, and each thing belongs_to parent):

```
@children = Thing.where(parent_id: @parents)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
def get_children
  @parents = current_user.parents.all
  @children = Children.where(parent_id: @parents.pluck(:id).uniq)
end
```